# How do I cycle through a range of dates in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, localdate

In my android project I need to go through data base and take some values from a current record, but only if this record has the date I need.

I tried googling it and i dont think there is a good enough explanation

Comment: share some code that you tried with the question then only we can get the answer

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/range-to.html#rangeto

Answer (score 0):

Save the current date in string form such as `'08/02/2023'` then convert it into date form through sdf(SimpleDateFormat)

```
val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
var date: String = "08/02/2023" //To be converted; in string form
val dateConverted: Date = sdf.parse(date) // Converted; in date form
```

The next step is to convert both the dates to be compared in to Date form and then compare through the if statement;
Example:

```
val date1: Date = <Your first date in date form>
val date2: Date = <Your second date in date form>
if(date1 == date2){
  // Do something
} else {
  // Do something
}
```

Conclusion:

```
for(date in <your date array>){
    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
    val date: Date = sdf.parse(date) // Converted; in date form
    if(date == <date you want to convert in Date form>){
       // Do something
    } else {
       // Do something
    }
}
```

This solution might help you.

Thank you

Comment: Don’t use Date. Use LocalDate. The `java.util` time-related classes should be avoided.

Comment: What @Tenfour04 said. `SimpleDateFormat` is a notorious troublemaker of a class and fortunately long outdated along with `Date`. Nobody should want to use any of them. Use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) or a Kotlin equivalent. The question was also tagged localdate.